# Jquery select - how to be more efficient?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some markup like so:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<span></span>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2 <a xyz="something"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to bind click event to the `<A>` tag, like this:

```
$("#mydiv A").click(this.function(){});
```

Can it be better? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that's as good as you get unless you want to change `"#mydiv A"` to `"a[xyz='something']"`

Comment: That's a perfectly acceptable way to do it. Did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: can what be better? selecting it like that is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure assign an `id` to the `<a>`

```
<a id="mylink" xyz="something"></a>

$("#mylink").click(this.function(){});
```

Comment: Would having too many ids in your dom, be considered bad for maintenance/readability?

Answer (score 0):

I would give the `<a>` tag an id and then attach a click listener like this:

```
$("#id_of_a_element").click(function() {

   alert("yep you clicked it");

});
```

This will give you greater accuracy under the div, on the other hand your method should work.

Comment: That really depends on the application. IDs can be expensive

Comment: Any docs that would back this up? This following doc says the lower the number of selectors the quicker it will find it: http://hungred.com/useful-information/jquery-optimization-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

That works .. you could define an ID for the  tag and select it directly - that's the fastest selecting method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select a specific element, it's always faster to select it directly by id. For example:

`<a id="myAnchor" xyn="something"></a>`

`$(#myAnchor).click(function() { alert('sup stallion');});`

If however you want to assign a click event for *all* anchor tags under `#mydiv` then your approach is fine.